# Looking for the effective method to solve the problem of "Loading Devices..." Problem in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio-3.0

I have installed the flutter and pasted it in my desired location ie `E:\\Installed Softwares\Flutter\flutter` and I have also Android Studio in my system. Everything is set. **I have set up the environment variables also.** The matter is that when I run the Android Studio and create a project either Flutter Project or Java project **the loading devices process stuck and I cannot able to run the code.**

Comment: run `flutter doctor` and attach that detail in your question.it will help us

Comment: There is no picture of attached IDE

Comment: Share the image of error and image of after you run flutter doctor

Comment: You might not installed your Android Studio, Install your Android Studio once again with proper Internet connection